# plus 1 to filename

Tags: bash, sed, mv

My task is log rotation and I can't find any command which can some number from filename with 1.

For example, I have some files with name: `wrapper.log.1`, `wrapper.log.2`. 
I need to rename and move that files to other directory and get `wrapper_1.log`, `wrapper_2.log`. After file was moved it should be deleted from origin directory.

It is possible, that in new folder there are files with the same name.
So, I should get last file and plus 1 to its filename like `wrapper_(2+1).log`.

For whole my task I found something like

```
find . -name "wrapper.log.*"
mkdir $(date '+ %d.%m.%y')
find . -name "wrapper.log.*" |sort -r |head -n1 | sed -E 's/(.log)(.[0-9])/_$(2+1)\1/'
```

But, of course, it doesn`t work after second line.

And, in future, it needs to be in bash.

P.S: Also, I think, It is possible to create just new file in new folder with timestamp or smth like that as postfix.
For example:

```
folder        file
01.01.19    wrapper_00_00_01
            wrapper_00_01_07
            wrapper_01_10_53
            wrapper_13_07_11

02.01.19
            wrapper_01_00_01
            wrapper_03_01_07
            wrapper_05_10_53
            wrapper_13_07_11
```

Comment: If you're making a new directory with the intent of putting the log files in it, why worry about name conflicting with previously existing files?

Comment: Because it is possible that folder can contain files with exact name which I should copy. I mean, that new folders creates once per day, but log files rotate from origin folder in range ....log.1 to ....log.10. So, if i`ll just copy files into new folder, after some time it happens, that wrapper.log.1 erase file in new folder with name wrapper_1.log, but it should be wrapper_11.log

Comment: either you're making a NEW directory -- `mkdir $(date '+ %d.%m.%y')` or you're copying files into an already existing directory.  Which is it?

Comment: I need to create new folder every day in 00:00, approximately

Comment: just out of curiosity: Why reinventing the wheel and write your own log rotation instead of using logrotate (https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate) which should be existant on most linux systems?

Comment: because it can`t rename my filename from origin folder depends on filename in new folder. It just delete/copy/move file from 1 folder to other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the highest number of the wrapper_ log files:

`find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec basename {} \; | ggrep -Po '(?<=wrapper_)[0-9]' | sort -rn | head -n 1`

I'm using grep's pearl switch to do a look-behind for "wrapper_", then reverse sorting the numbers found and taking the first one. If you want to generate a new file name, I'd use `awk`, e.g:

`find . -type f -name "*.log" -exec basename {} \; | ggrep -Po '(?<=wrapper_)[0-9]' | sort -rn | head -n 1 |  awk '{print "wrapper_"$1 + 1".log" }'`

This will produce a file name with the next number in the sequence.

Comment: thank you. It is close to be truth. But I changed a little bit your line to 
----
find . -type f -name "wrapper*"  |grep -Po '[0-9]{1,3}' |sort -rn |head -n1 |awk '{print "servicemix_"$1+1".log"}' 
---

Comment: I can`t understand, what does mean '(?<=wrapper_)' in your codeline

Comment: @Dred it's a regex [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: `(?!pattern)`  ==> A zero-width negative look-ahead assertion.                                    `(?<=pattern)`  ==>  A zero-width positive look-behind assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question entirely but I know that using a dollar-sign and double brackets you can execute a calculation:

```
Prompt>echo $((1+1))
2
```

Comment: But i cant get first digit to plus 1, to get new number for my new filename.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found two solutions.
First, it`s bash, smth like this

```
#!/bin/bash

#DECLARE

FILENAME=$1
DATE=$(date '+%d.%m.%y')
SRC_DIR="/usr/local/apache-servicemix-6.1.0/data/log"
DEST_DIR="/mnt/smxlog/$HOSTNAME"

#START

mkdir -m 777 "$DEST_DIR/$DATE"

if [ -d "$DEST_DIR/$DATE" ]
then

for f in $(find "$SRC_DIR/" -name "$FILENAME.log.*") 

do

TIME=$(date '+%H_%M_%S.%3N')
NEW_FILENAME="$FILENAME-$TIME.log"
NEW_DEST_WITH_FILE="$DEST_DIR/$DATE/$NEW_FILENAME"

mv $f $NEW_DEST_WITH_FILE
gzip "$NEW_DEST_WITH_FILE"

done

else 
exit 1
fi

#END
```

And the second variant is using log4j logger properties, but it should to upload to servicemix system folder log4j-1.2.17_fragment.jar and apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17_fragment. May be it is possible to upload them as bundle, I didn`t try.
Both jar use different API. There are
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html and 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/apidocs/index.html?overview-summary.html
And properties will be

```
log4j.logger.wrapper.log=DEBUG, wrapper
log4j.additivity.logger.wrapper.log=false
log4j.appender.wrapper=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.wrapper.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy  
#This setting should be used with commented line log4j.appender.wrapper.File=... if it needs to zip to target directory immediately
#log4j.appender.wrapper.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/mnt/smxlog/${env:HOSTNAME}/wrapper.%d{HH:mm:ss}.log.gz
#Or it is possible to log and zip in the same folder, and after that with cron replace zipped files to required folder 
log4j.appender.wrapper.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${karaf.data}/log/wrapper.%d{HH:mm:ss}.log.gz
log4j.appender.wrapper.File=${karaf.data}/log/wrapper.log
log4j.appender.wrapper.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  
#Size in bytes
log4j.appender.wrapper.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=1000000
log4j.appender.wrapper.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.wrapper.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] - %m%n
log4j.appender.wrapper.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.wrapper.append=true
```